# Does Gitlab registry compress container images?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-image

While looking for reduce the size of a docker image created with the gitlab-ci, I realized that the size that gitlab shows me in the container registry menu is not the same as I can see whith `docker images` in CLI after pulling the image from the repo.

I thought that gitlab auto compress the images and find  [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/reduce_container_registry_storage.html) in the gitlab documentation that says "**Image layers are stored on the storage backend in the original (usually compressed) format.**"

But I feel like it's vague (or I don't understand) and I want to know how you control the compression of your image in gitlab ?